# Web Design Standards - Accessibility

Tags: web-applications, web, web-deployment-project

Can anyone inform me of any official documentation (i.e. w3c) that instructs developers on what keyboard buttons should activate components/set functionality on a given page?

For example,

A user tabs onto a check box; should enter be pressed to select/de-select it or another button?

Comment: There is the [WAI website](http://www.w3.org/WAI/) that contains a lot of documentation and guides about accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make your website compliant with w3c accessibility guidelines its good to read the whole [WCAG guide](http://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20). Specifically the keyboard part you can find [here](http://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/quickref/#keyboard-operation)